# i need to plot a graph on microsoft visual c++ 2008

Tags: c++

i need to present an array on agraph
like function bar(array_name) in matlab 
how can i do that in microsoft visual c++ 2008

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that with standard C++ alone. You'll have to use some library for graph plotting. You either use something general and low level like GDI or OpenGL, or you use a dedicated graph drawing library. Check this question for a list of such libraries: [Graph Drawing C++ Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library).

Comment: Unfortunately that question's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this, http://www.omeyasweb.com/mschart-control-para-visual-studio-2008/ it's in spanish but surely you can use google translator to follow these steps